# Install Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I install Ruby on Rails in my PC? What files do I need to download and what is the installation procedure?

Comment: The official guide is located here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#installing-ruby

Answer (score 1):

1. Download RubyInstaller 1.8.7 [from here](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/archives). During the installation, check the 'Add Ruby executables to your PATH' box. After the installation, don't forget to restart `cmd`. Try `ruby -v` and `gem -v` to check for installed Ruby and RubyGems and ensure they work;
2. Install the latest stable Rails release: `gem install rails` and check it using `rails -v`;
3. Create a new application using `rails myapp`;
4. `cd myapp`, run `script/server`, and develop, develop, develop.

Comment: I did not follow Step 3 and Step 4 .....do we just need to give rail application name ???? and how to run script/server

Comment: Yeah, you need to assign some name to your Rails application. You can find more information regarding the `rails` command line utility using `rails --help`. `rails` in Rails 3 will show `rails new APP_PATH [options]`, so you should launch it like `rails new hello_world_app`.

Comment: Ok i have created a sample application. how do i view it in browser...sorry for my ignorance....just started with this.......

Comment: Change your working directory `cd your_app_name`, type `script/server`, wait a little bit (Ruby and Rails are slow on Windows), and point your browser to `localhost:3000`.

Comment: When i started the server i got the error message, Could not find gem mysql2 in any of the gem sources...!!!!

Comment: You should try to install it using `gem install mysql2` or replace it in your Gemfile to `mysql`, then `bundle install` and try to run the server again.

Comment: I have created a sample Ruby Application. Now i would like to connect to a database and start working on it. Somebody please help me on the steps to follow.

Comment: @DanielO'Hara, your link of ruby installer is broken now